# How save a string to a file in Android to be able to read it later?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to implement the section "Using the Internal Storage" in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I think I did the first part correctly, saving string to a file, but how do I read the string later?

Her is what my code looks like:

```
String FILEPROFILE = "profileinfo";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
BufferedInputStream fis = null;
OutputStream out = null;


          try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILEPROFILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(profile.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        try {
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILEPROFILE));
            Log.d("UsersThoughts", "BufferedInputStream is " + fis.read());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

EDIT:
I change it to this:

```
 try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILEPROFILE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Log.d("UsersThoughts", "This blah object read " + fis.read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("UsersThoughts", "This blah object trying to read: " + e.toString());
        }

          try{
              Log.d("UsersThoughts", "This blah object toString " + fis.toString());
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("UsersThoughts", "This blah object trying to make string: " + e.toString());
          }
```

The output in the logcat looks like this:

```
 11-15 18:41:34.862: D/UsersThoughts(7777): This blah object read123
 11-15 18:41:34.862: D/UsersThoughts(7777): This blah object toString java.io.FileInputStream@46356128
```

Looks like it's reading the files as bites....how do I get the text back that I copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the answer i gave here to store a String to a file in Android: [Should I store data in sqlite in case user is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392966/should-i-store-data-in-sqlite-in-case-user-is-offline/13393375#13393375)

Comment: this looks promising. ill give it a shot when im back home

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting this from the same source you've cited:

> To read a file from internal storage:
>
> 1. Call openFileInput() and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
> 2. Read bytes from the file with read().
> 3. Then close the stream with close().

**EDIT:** For example,

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("FILENAME");
BufferedInputStream blah = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
```

Then do whatever you were doing earlier with this `blah` object.

Comment: can you cite an example of implementation? Having trouble getting it to work